# How to get the form layout after upgrading from bootstrap 2 to bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The bootstrap 2 html codes:

```
<div class="control-group required">
<label class="control-label">Identifiers</label>
<div class="controls">
<span>
    <div class="multiple-inputs">
        <div id="id5e">
            <div id="0NtcA_0" class="">
                <select class="medium" name="id="id52">
                <option selected="selected" value="0">Callsign</option>
                <option value="1">EIDR</option>
                <option value="2">InternalAssetURI</option>
                <option value="3">MasterSourceID</option>
                <option value="4">PAID</option>
                <option value="5">Other</option>
                <option value="6">ROVI</option>
                <option value="7">TMS</option>
                <option value="8">URI</option>
                </select> <input type="text" value="SC001" id="id5f" class="input-xlarge" data-original-title="">
                <a class="btn btn-delete btn-mini" id="id53" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Remove</a>
            </div>
            <div id="0NtcA_1" class="">       
                <select class="medium" name="" id="id54">
                    <option selected="selected" value="">Choose One</option>
                    <option value="0">Callsign</option>
                    <option value="1">EIDR</option>
                    <option value="2">InternalAssetURI</option>
                    <option value="3">MasterSourceID</option>
                    <option value="4">PAID</option>
                    <option value="5">Other</option>
                    <option value="6">ROVI</option>
                    <option value="7">TMS</option>
                    <option value="8">URI</option>
                </select> <input type="text" value="" name="" id="id60" class="input-xlarge" data-original-title="">
                 <a class="btn btn-delete btn-mini" id="id55" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Remove</a>
             </div>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-mini" id="id56" href="#"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add</a>
    </div>
</span>
</div>
```

For class "controls" have been removed from bootstrap 3, how can the layout be achieved in bootstrap3?

For I could not post image for the short of reputation, the layout of the above is like:

```
Identifiers  | Select DropDown box1 |  | Text Box 01 |    | Remove Button |
             | Select DropDown box2 |  | Text Box 02 |    | Remove Button |
             | Select DropDown box3 |  | Text Box 03 |    | Remove Button |
             | Add Button |
```

Answer (score 0):

Id split your divs up into the new bootstrap 3 layout format...

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     //options
     //options
     //options
     //select
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
     //options
     //options
     //options
     //select
   </div>
</div>
```

basically you divide your rows into 12 sections.... you can use two divs that are 6 and 6... 4 divs set at 3... 3x4=12.. any number that equals up to 12... The `sm` at  `class="col-_-#"` is important as well.. Please review this documentation to see examples and explanations.

[Migrating bootstrap from BS2 to BS3](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration)

[Understanding Bootstrap 3 Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: If I can post a image , it will be clearer. I want: Identifier is a label, all Select boxes, text boxes and buttons are located at its right.  And every line can be removed by click the remove button. It seems like that the label "Identifier" is a column, and all the other form-controls are in a column.  In bootstrap2, we use  <div class="controls"> to contain all the other form-controls, but in bootstrap3, there is no controls class defined.

Comment: Its a little confusing.. maybe linking to an image may help

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Identifiers</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <span>
              <div class="multiple-inputs">
                  <div id="id5e">
                      <div id="0NtcA_0" class="">
                          <select class="medium" name="id=" id52"="">
                          <option selected="selected" value="0">Callsign</option>
                          <option value="1">EIDR</option>
                          <option value="2">InternalAssetURI</option>
                          <option value="3">MasterSourceID</option>
                          <option value="4">PAID</option>
                          <option value="5">Other</option>
                          <option value="6">ROVI</option>
                          <option value="7">TMS</option>
                          <option value="8">URI</option>
                          </select> <input type="text" value="SC001" id="id5f" class="input-xlarge form-control" data-original-title="">
                          <a class="btn btn-delete btn-default btn-xs" id="id53" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Remove</a>
                      </div>
                      <div id="0NtcA_1" class="">       
                          <select class="medium" name="" id="id54">
                              <option selected="selected" value="">Choose One</option>
                              <option value="0">Callsign</option>
                              <option value="1">EIDR</option>
                              <option value="2">InternalAssetURI</option>
                              <option value="3">MasterSourceID</option>
                              <option value="4">PAID</option>
                              <option value="5">Other</option>
                              <option value="6">ROVI</option>
                              <option value="7">TMS</option>
                              <option value="8">URI</option>
                          </select> <input type="text" value="" name="" id="id60" class="input-xlarge form-control" data-original-title="">
                           <a class="btn btn-delete btn-default btn-xs" id="id55" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Remove</a>
                       </div>
                  </div>
                  <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="id56" href="#"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add</a>
              </div>
          </span>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also use a online migration tool , http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader/ may it will help you.